# How to change matplotlib pcolor colobar tick font size?

Tags: matplotlib

I try to change the font size of the ticks on colorbar. It is not the x or y axis ticks; but, the ticks of the "color bar" appeared on the right side of the plt.pcolor plot.

I searched online, and found a couple of suggestions, e.g.,

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=150)
cbar = plt.pcolor(x, y, z, cmap='jet')
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(cbar.ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=20)
```

But, it does not change the tick font size of the colorbar.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to change the size of the *ticks* or the size of the *tick labels*?

Comment: @AJBiffl I am trying to change the size of the numbers on the ticks, not the label.

Comment: Those would be the tick labels, and @Jody Klymak's answer will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly how you would do it for a normal axis (at least for 3.4.3)

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

pc = ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(20, 20))
cb = fig.colorbar(pc)

cb.ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=16)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! It works!